# Get an element's id where there is none?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

So, I am using [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) which has this stupid requirement that it needs an element's `id` attribute to plot.

However, my javascript uses jQuery, which operates on elements, and I don't want to rely on a div having an id.

Can I somehow, given a jQuery `$(this)` element, generate an `id` on the fly for a div and pass that id to my jqPlot function?

Something like this:

```
(function($){  //jquery plugin style
  $.fn.myPlot = function(){
       //Somehow get id for "this"
       var generatedId = somehowCreateID(this);
       jqPlot.plot( generatedId );
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Since IDs must be guarenteed to be unqiue, but do not need to be random, it's much better to just use a monotonically increasing ID number with an alpha prefix like this:

```
function assignID(elem, prefix) {
   prefix = prefix || "autoId_";
   if (elem.id) {
      return (elem.id);
   } else {
       if (!assignID.cntr) {
           assignID.cntr = 1;
       }
       var id = prefix + assignID.cntr++;
       elem.id = id;
       return(id);
   }   
}
```

This uses a property of the function `assignID.cntr` to keep track of a counter that increments one each time it's used so the IDs assigned here will never be the same as a previously assigned ID.

You can then make sure any element always has an id by just doing this:

```
assignID(elem, "plot");
```

If you want a jQuery method that would do this, then you could do it like this:

```
jQuery.assignIDCntr = 1;
jQuery.fn.assignID = function(prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || "autoId_";
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!this.id) {
            this.id = prefix + jQuery.assignIDCntr++;
        }   
    });
}
```

And, then you would use it like this:

```
$(".myobjects").assignID("plot");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateID(element) {
    var id;
    do {
        id = "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
    } while (document.getElementById(id) != null);

    element.id = id;
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter prefixed with at least one letter (to be compliant with non-HTML5 documents):

```
(function($) {
    var counter = 0;
    $.fn.myPlot = function() {
       return this.each(function() {
           jqPlot.plot(this.id || (this.id = "plot" + counter++));
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```